# Confusion with the following selection sort code

Tags: c, selection-sort

```
int i, j, t;

for (i = 0; i < n - 1 ; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        if (a[i] > a[j]) {
            t = a[i]; 
            a[i] = a[j]; 
            a[j] = t;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is whether the above code is correct selection sort code or not? I got this code from various books. If it is incorrect then please explain why.

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: Yes, after execution of the code resultant array is sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the code is correct. Basically it will take costly `O(n^2)` to sort the array in ascending order.

At each step `i [0..n-1]`, you are putting the smallest element among indexes `[i..n-1]` at index `i`.

The *swap* function makes sure that you are continuously *placing* the smaller value of the two compared values at `i` index.

Comment: How would you modify the code shown to make it into a bubble sort?  It looks to me like a bubble sort, not a selection sort.

Answer (score 1):

In my view, the sort shown in the question is a bubble sort, not a selection sort.

Amongst other chunks of code I have kicking around in my archive, I have a test-bed for different sort algorithms.  And the test-bed includes bubble, selection, insertion and quick sorts, and it monitors comparisons and swaps.

The code for bubble sort and selection sort is:

```
static void selection_sort(Data a[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        int min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            inc_comps();
            if (a[j] < a[min])
                min = j;
        }
        inc_comps();
        if (min != i)
            swap(&a[min], &a[i]);
    }
}

static void bubble_sort(Data a[], int n)
{
    for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            inc_comps();
            if (a[j] > a[j+1])
                swap(&a[j], &a[j+1]);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't now recall why the outer loop of the bubble sort counts down rather than up, but the more important point is that the selection sort is noticeably different from the code shown in the question — and the code in the question matches bubble sort much more closely.

You can also look in Wikipedia for [Sorting Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) which has these and many other algorithms outlined, and links to multiple sources of information about sorting.

The test-bed runs the different algorithms with different data patterns on different sized data sets.  Part of the output is for 10,000 rows of data (type `int`):

```
 Number             Filler    Sorter       Compares          Swaps             Time
  10000             Random     Quick         151583          88111 PASS    0.000593
  10000             Random    Bubble       49995000       24895500 PASS    0.143897
  10000             Random Insertion       24905489       24895500 PASS    0.028966
  10000             Random Selection       50004999           9986 PASS    0.040409
  10000          Ascending     Quick         151719          90480 PASS    0.000584
  10000          Ascending    Bubble       49995000       24876354 PASS    0.141219
  10000          Ascending Insertion       24886345       24876354 PASS    0.022601
  10000          Ascending Selection       50004999           9988 PASS    0.041173
  10000         Descending     Quick         119881          74247 PASS    0.000251
  10000         Descending    Bubble       49995000       49995000 PASS    0.081584
  10000         Descending Insertion       49995000       49995000 PASS    0.055118
  10000         Descending Selection       50004999           5000 PASS    0.050586
  10000 Forward Organ Pipe     Quick       25000000       25005000 PASS    0.034033
  10000 Forward Organ Pipe    Bubble       49995000       24995000 PASS    0.070633
  10000 Forward Organ Pipe Insertion       25004999       24995000 PASS    0.022398
  10000 Forward Organ Pipe Selection       50004999           9987 PASS    0.048300
  10000 Reverse Organ Pipe     Quick       25005002       16665004 PASS    0.025632
  10000 Reverse Organ Pipe    Bubble       49995000       24995000 PASS    0.064798
  10000 Reverse Organ Pipe Insertion       25000000       24995000 PASS    0.022568
  10000 Reverse Organ Pipe Selection       50004999           9886 PASS    0.053838
  10000            Uniform     Quick       49995000          19998 PASS    0.030855
  10000            Uniform    Bubble       49995000              0 PASS    0.038719
  10000            Uniform Insertion           9999              0 PASS    0.000021
  10000            Uniform Selection       50004999              0 PASS    0.041021
```

As you can see from the data, selection sort scores well on the number of swaps it performs, but not so well on the number of comparisons.  This would give you a way to validate my observation that the algorithm in the question is a bubble sort, not a selection sort.